# Do a full render for what I am seeing without changing the default camera?

Tags: camera

Suppose that I have set an animation to the default camera. I can still view other parts of the scene in the viewport and even see a low-quality rendered view by clicking the empty ball icon.

But what if I want to see the full render for the current view? I could change the viewport render settings, but that would make all subsequent preview slower and I would have to change them back after seeing the full render.

I can press Ctrl+Alt+Num0, but that changes the default camera, which I don't want. I have added another camera, but I don't know how to make Ctrl+Alt+Num0 to change the second camera, not affecting the default camera. Is this possible?

Also, pressing Ctrl+Alt+Num0 does not even exactly set the camera as I see in the viewport; the area that the camera is changed to see is only the centre part of the viewport, so when rendered, it is not showing what I see in the viewport.

- The view that I wanted render.

[image]

- What pressing Ctrl+Alt+Num0 and F12 will render.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me adress both those problems:

1. Your *viewport view* and *camera view* don't match, because they have a different *Focal Length*.
   Go to *Sidebar > View > Focal Length* and adjust the numbers, so they're the same

[image]

2. To align a different camera to view, you need to make it the active camera - go to *Properties > Scene > Camera* and choose your new one.
   Then go to *View > Align View > Align Active Camera to View* (or press <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Num0</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: For (1), by default, both the viewport and the camera had the focal length of 50mm. So, the same value does not seem to work. In my case, I tried something like 20mm for the camera, then when I pressed the shortcut, the area that the camera sees sort-of matched the viewport (but not exactly). That is fine, because it was close enough. The only inconvenience is that when that shortcut is pressed, the camera region is still a small rectangle at the centre of the viewport, and the region I was seeing gets shrunken inside of that rectangle. (Render results are as I expected.)

Comment: You're right :). When you align a camera, it aligns it's origin point. So you need to zoom out a bit to get the correct view. Also, the focal length is influenced by the size of the camera's sensor. Anyway, good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Press Numpad 0 to view what the camera is seeing, select the new camera and press G Z Z (Which means move the camera along its own Z axis), move the mouse until you get the desired framing (like if you put a real camera closer or far from the subject) and confirm with left click.

You will get the same framing of the viewport only if the viewport and the camera have the same focal lenght (both are 50 mm as default).